# Delete all rows which does not start with at least 3 digit

Tags: shell, sed

Delete all rows which does not start with at least 3 digit.
I use below sed command but it removes title as well.

How can I start below command from line 2, so that title remains as it is.

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{3\}/p' my_file
```

I have used below as well but does not work.

```
sed -n '2,${/^[0-9]\{3\}/p}' my_file
```

Comment: Title? Please post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Did you try `sed -e '2,${/^[0-9]\{3\}/d}' my_file`?

Comment: @James Title is first row. So this command should start from row number 2.

Comment: File content is as below.
Name               OS              Version
11 test              Windows    5.1
764                  MS              12.7
222 test           Mac            10
test                  Android       7.0
2nd test           IOS             11.0


I want result as below.
Name               OS              Version
764                  MS              12.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1b;/^[0-9]\{3\}/!d' file
```

Do not process the first line. If any line thereafter does not begin with at least 3 digits, delete it.

N.B. `-i` option replaces the contents of the old file with the amended file. If multiple files are placed following the sed commands, they will be treated separately i.e. each files header will be remain. To achieve the same effect without over writing the files use the `-s` option.

Another way:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{3\}/b;1!d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
$ cat foo
Title
11 test
222 test
test
$ awk '/^[0-9]{3}/ || NR==1' foo
Title
222 test
```

**Edit:** *Title is first row. So this command should start from row number 2.*

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]{3}/ || NR>1' foo
222 test
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. All you need to do is:

```
sed -e '2,${/^[0-9]\{3\}/d}' my_file
```

This will begin executing the script beginning from the second line (excludes the first one, which I assume it's the title you're talking about).

Comment: This is the right answer. You should explain a bit more, on why using `d` worked replacing `n` and `p` flags

Comment: @Maroun, The command you posted replacing -n with -e and p with d will remove all lines which starts with numbers. My requirement is opposite. Delete all lines which does not start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For [portability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed), try:

```
sed -n '1p;2,${/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]/p}' my_file
```

Or `sed -in '1p;2,${/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]/p}' my_file` to edit *my_file* directly.

Comment: sed command sed -n '2,${/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]/p}' my_file works but it deletes first row/line as well. First row/line is title/heading. this command is not starting from line no.2

Comment: @Majeed, Fixed, please try now.